# dynamically edit row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am perform add ,edit and delete operation using jquery.

i have create product.html file and jsproduct.js file.

[image]

My Question is i am click edit button and change selectbox value and press edit 
product button

but select box value can not display table

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/kishankakadiya/m6sn39hp/1/embed/"></script>
```

[Check Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kishankakadiya/m6sn39hp/1/)

Comment: Cleaver way of adding _ONLY_  fiddle link

Comment: "but select box value can not display table"...what do you mean?

Comment: @thepio  step:1   i have product category selectbox and i am select product category value in select box like(product category :mobile,computer etc) and change category value after click edit button ,but change category value can not display gridview(means table)

Comment: @thepio  view check demo

Comment: @thepio  click link      https://jsfiddle.net/kishankakadiya/m6sn39hp/1/

Comment: @kishankakadiyaI added an working answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same id for the `<td>`elements on your table. You are using the counter with this and the result is having more than one `<td id="1">` and jQuery will not handle it correctly.

I changed your td's to use a class instead of id and added a class prefix to your td's like this:

```
'<td class="category-' + this.counter + ' ">' + product_category +'</td>'
'<td class="name-' + this.counter + '">' + product_name + '</td>'
```

And in your edit function I used the class as a selector:

```
$(".category-" + this.id).text(product_category);
$('.name-' + this.id).text(product_name);
```

Then it works correctly. You still have some trouble in setting your mode etc but hopefully you can get those fixed by yourself.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ye6mugxe/1/

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!